# In Java, how to remove an object from a list of objects in between iteration if condition is met and process the rest objects

Tags: java, for-loop

I am iterating over a list of POJO objects called `txnList` (say, size = 2). If an object falls into an invalid criteria, then I am removing it from this `txnList` list (now, size = 1). However, I want to process the rest of the elements in `txnList` but since the size is 1, it doesn't process further and exits from the top most loop altogether.

Below is my code, with bare minimum essential details:

```
for (OrgTransaction txn : txnList) {
    String txnId = txn.getTxnNumber());
    Order order = util.getOrder(txnId);
    
    boolean isInvalid = false;
    List<CollectionType> collectionTypeList = util.getCollectionType(order);
    for (CollectionType collectionType : collectionTypeList) {
        if (isNotValid(collectionType)) {
            // first transaction in the list is invalid so it enters here
            txnList.remove(txn);
            isInvalid = true;
            // Breaking since we do not want to process anything in this nested list if one of the invalid things is found.
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isInvalid) {
        // process only valid transactions further      
    }
    // NOTE: now after first iteration of processing invalid case, this should go to top to iterate 2nd transaction but it just returns from the list since the new size is 1 and 1 time the `txnList` loop has iterated.
}
```

FYI: No exception is thrown in this code as a result of deletion

Comment: Does your code run without throwing an exception? AFAIK, you are not allowed to delete an object from a list while iterating it. At least not the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the item with the iterator, which needs to know about the operation.

```
for (Iterator<OrgTransaction> iterator = txnList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
   OrgTransaction txn = iterator.next();

   ... 
   iterator.remove();
   ... 
}
```

This also avoids exceptions due to concurrent modification.

Comment: Thank you @Andy Thomas and all others who replied.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possible ways:

1. create a list of elements you want to remove, then use list.removeAll(removeList)

```
for(...){
 if (isInvalid) {
    removeList.add(txn)
}
...
txnList.removeAll(removeList);
```

2. while traversing a list, create a new list which does not contain elements you do not need. Then just reassign.

```
for(...){
 if (!isInvalid) {
    newList.add(txn)
}
...
txnList = newList;
```

Comment: The second option here is a common idiom, and a good way to go. +1

Answer (score -1):

One method you can use is to just use a for loop and decrement the index each time you remove an element:

```
for (int x = 0; x < txnList.size(); x++;) {
    txn = txn.get(x); //define txn
    String txnId = txn.getTxnNumber());
    Order order = util.getOrder(txnId);
    
    boolean isInvalid = false;
    List<CollectionType> collectionTypeList = util.getCollectionType(order);
    for (CollectionType collectionType : collectionTypeList) {
        if (isNotValid(collectionType)) {
            // first transaction in the list is invalid so it enters here
            txnList.remove(txn);
            x--; //decrement index
            isInvalid = true;
            // Breaking since we do not want to process anything in this nested list if one of the invalid things is found.
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isInvalid) {
        // doSomething      
    }
    // NOTE: now after first iteration of processing invalid case, this should go to top to iterate 2nd transaction but it just returns from the list since the new size is 1 and 1 time the `txnList` loop has iterated.
}
```